# Website crashing on tablet/mobile

Tags: html, css, animation, mobile, crash

I built this [website](http://spencerpopedesign.com/lfa/browse.html). It works fine on desktop, however, when I try to access it on either mobile or tablet devices it causes the browser to crash. I have a gut feeling that this is due to a large css animation on the index page as the browse.html page does in fact work. I am wondering if there is some reason the css would cause this problem/ looking for a suggestion on how to correct it (is there a way I can program the site to bypass the css animation when displayed on certain screen sizes)?

Answer (score 0):

I know I can use a media query with `display:none` for the class, but I'm more interested in why this problem occurs?

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS file should be fine. If anything is causing it to crash on mobile, it would probably be the scripts. You could try process of elimination with those and see who the culprit is.

On the CSS file, you should use a minifier which will help the browser load large CSS files faster. http://cssminifier.com/

Comment: Its the weirdest thing. I tried process of elimination and setting the css to `display: none` fixes the problem. I really don't understand why this would be a problem.